# How to fix .htaccess permissions to solve error 500?

Tags: php, .htaccess, permissions, http-status-code-500

I've accidentally changed permissions for my public_html and its child files/folders. Now I can't access my website as it's returning a 500 error. I am able to access [theailona.com/index.html](https://theailona.com/index.html) but not `theailona.com` or `theailona.com/index.php`.

I tried to test if .htaccess is working using [Bolt's htaccess tester](https://docs.bolt.cm/4.0/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works#test-if-htaccess-is-working), but accessing the [htaccess_tester.php](https://theailona.com/htaccess_tester.php) file returns the same 500. So I'm assuming that PHP files aren't being executed properly.

- `index.html`, `php.ini`, `.user.ini`, and `.htaccess` are all currently set to 644.
- `index.php` and `htaccess_tester.php` are set to 755.

Root .htaccess content as follows:

```
# .htaccess in your images directory
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond &#37;{REQUEST_URI} ^\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F,L]


# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit -1
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea3"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit -1
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea3"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

Error log isn't showing anything new, the latest entry is from about an hour ago (assuming it's server timezone).

`[Thu Nov 12 12:23:05.126846 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 29891:tid 47490327906048] [client 220.240.160.42:52376] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/k5403444/public_html/.htaccess`

Would love your kind help in solving this so I can set up a flat-file CMS which uses PHP.

Comment: Hi, I've included the error log at the bottom of the post.
To be honest I'm not too sure myself. Before today, the file was last updated in 2014 and I'm not familiar with .htaccess rules, so I must have gotten that from somewhere online.

Comment: There are some directives used in this .htaccess that are not allowed in Apache config. Start with a blank .htaccess and keep adding each block to see which one that is.

Comment: Does the `/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea3` directory exist and is read/writable to your "www" user? Regarding, "*index.php and htaccess_tester.php are set to 755.*" PHP script files should also be 644 (or 640 when using group memberships of the "www" user), unless you are executing them with a shebang.

Comment: @anubhava I tried deleting .htaccess and it's still coming up with 500.

Comment: @WillB. no, the `/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea3` directory does not exist in public_html. Thanks for the heads-up, changed PHP to 644.

Comment: "`/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea3` directory does not exist in public_html." - It's not supposed to exist "in public_html" - that is an absolute filesystem path, not a document-root relative URL-path. Does that path exist on your _server_? If you also have a `.user.ini` file then your `.htaccess` may not be doing anything useful anyway. What is in `.user.ini`? What are the permissions of the `public_html` directory itself?

Comment: @MrWhite `public_html` is set to 755. above public_html is far as I can go, and there's no /var folder. `.user.ini` has the following content: https://pastebin.pl/view/1739c005

Comment: I saw other similar entries and fixing ownership of the directory/file solved the issue. `public_html` currently has *correctuser* as user, and *nobody* as group. Though any file/folders under public_html has *correctuser* as both user and group. Is this the right code to run via terminal? `chown -R :correctuser public_html`

Comment: "fixing ownership of the directory/file solved the issue" - You should add that as an answer and include what you did to solve the problem (and later "accept" it). Permissions and ownership. "there's no /var folder" - _you_ may not be able to access that folder, but that doesn't mean that PHP can't. `.user.ini` has the same settings as `.htaccess`. Quite possibly the directives in `.htaccess` are entirely superfluous.

Comment: The `nobody` group is typically used to allow the configured Apache owner/group read access as the "www" user. To clarify, when PHP is run through the CLI, it has the same owner/group as the user that executed it. When it is run from Apache (`mod_php`, `suexec`) or PHP-FPM (`fast-cgi`), as a service, PHP will have the owner/group that is specified in their configs, referred to in general as the "www" user.  Please verify your configs declared owner/group to ensure there are no  conflicts with the assigned directory owner/group.